# Is there a built in way to get date in 6 digit format YYMMDD?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I'm trying to create a function the will create a list of dates formatted in a 6 digit number starting from today till August of 2018. the result should be something like this:

```
[190322, 190321, 190320, ...]
```

I'm not sure if there is a built is a way to get the date in this 6 digit format?

Comment: Pop open your developer tools(F12), go to the console, type `Date.prototype.` and look at all the options you have.  Or look at the [MDN Date prototype documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype)

Comment: Best bet is to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString then string.split('T')[0].split('-').join('')

Comment: Did Y2K teach us nothing? Two digit years are a bad idea, *especially* in this wildly non-standard form.

Comment: I'm using this to download urls that use this format in the files name. I have no control over the naming

Comment: You really should do a search before asking a question, there are a huge number of duplicates for "[*how to format a date*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+format+a+date)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assisted by `Date` objects, you could proceed like this:

```js
function getDateNumsBetween(a, b) {
    // b should come before a
    a = new Date(a); // new instance to avoid side effects.
    const result = [];
    while (a >= b) {
        result.push(((a.getFullYear()%100)*100 + a.getMonth()+1)*100 + a.getDate());
        a.setDate(a.getDate()-1);
    }
    return result;
}

const result = getDateNumsBetween(new Date(), new Date("August 1, 2018"));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!this is very helpful, the only issue here is that the year is in 3 digit number. I want it in 2 digit number

Comment: Right, that is now fixed.

Comment: Oh nice answer - didn't thought about multiplying! @tito.300 this should be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no build in "one function do it all" to get your outcome right away.

### Option 1:

However you can use the provided functions `getFullYear`, `getMonth` and `getDate` to get to your result:

```
let d = new Date()
let formatted = d.getFullYear().toString().slice(2,4) +
(d.getMonth()+1 > 10 ? d.getMonth()+1 : `0${d.getMonth()+1}`) +
(d.getDate() > 10 ? d.getDate() : `0${d.getDate()}`)-0
```

Lets get through it line by line

```
// Uses the getFullYear function which will return 2019, ...
d.getFullYear().toString().slice(2,4) // "19"
```

```
// getMonth returns 0-11 so we have to add one month, 
// since you want the leading zero we need to also 
// check for the length before adding it to the string
(d.getMonth()+1 < 10 ? d.getMonth()+1 : `0${d.getMonth()+1}`) // "03"
```

```
// uses getDate as it returns the date number; getDay would 
// result in a the index of the weekday
(d.getDate() < 10 ? d.getDate() : `0${d.getDate()}`) // "22"
```

```
// will magically convert the string "190322" into an integer 190322
-0
```

Might be worth saying that this is a quick "how to achieve" it without installing any npm package but make sure to cover edge cases yourself as there are many when it comes to dates.

### Option 2:

Another option would be to go for the `toISOString` and use split, a bit of regex, and slice to receive your outcome:

```
d.toISOString().split('T')[0].replace(/\-/g, '').slice(2,8)-0
```

Again step by step with the output:

```
d.toISOString() // "2019-03-22T22:13:12.975Z"
```

```
d.toISOString().split('T') // (2) ["2019-03-22", "22:13:12.975Z"]
```

```
d.toISOString().split('T')[0] // "2019-03-22"
```

```
d.toISOString().split('T')[0].replace(/\-/g, '') // "20190322"
```

```
d.toISOString().split('T')[0].replace(/\-/g, '').slice(2,8) // "190322"
```

```
d.toISOString().split('T')[0].replace(/\-/g, '').slice(2,8)-0 // 190322
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to do it with the second option with a little modification: let d = new Date().toISOString(); 
d.split('T')[0].split('-').join('').slice(2, 8);

Comment: your option 1 uses `> 2` when it should be checking for `> 1`

Comment: Be aware that `toISOString` renders a UTC date, so if local time and UTC equivalent are on two different days you may get undesired results.

Comment: @Asthmatic good catch but a check for the length was wrong all along - needed to check for the number itself being > 10 as length would only be possible on the string :)

Comment: Checking for length that way worked when it was a string but treating is as an integer like you changed it to works just as well